# Decoding HECV with FFMpeg. Multiple slices I frame issue

Tags: ffmpeg, slice, rtsp

I'm facing issue decoding camera with HEVC codec and RTSP transport (live555). I'm trying to decode frames with ffmpeg (avcodec_send_packet/avcodec_receive_frame) but it decodes only the first 1/3 of the picture and the others 2/3 stay green rectangle. Each frame is sent divided into 3 parts (slices) :

- I-Frame is I-B-I
- P-Frame is P-P-P

I suppose FFmpeg is able to deal with this because it agrees with HEVC specification.
Have I to "concatenate" 3 slices before send them to ffmpeg ?
Could you help me please?

I try to send all slices before receive them but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg's H264 decoder indeed needs full frames as input. You can't send it individual slices. You can concatenate them yourself, or use a bitstream filter / parser which will do it for you. In this case, manual concatenation will probably work fine.

Answer (score 0):

before sending it to the decoder, you have to merge the slices, between slices add 4 bytes and set the value to 0001, and send it to the decoder.

you can follow this pseudocode

```
size_t data_pos = 4;
memmove(rtp_data + data_pos, rtp_data, frameSize);
rtp_data[0]=0;rtp_data[1]=0;rtp_data[2]=0;rtp_data[3]=1;
frameSize += data_pos;

if (firstFU){
                memset(temp_rtp_data, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                memcpy(temp_rtp_data, rtp_data, frameSize);
                temp_buffer_size = frameSize;
                firstFU = false;
}
else{
                
                memcpy(temp_rtp_data + temp_buffer_size, rtp_data, frameSize);
                temp_buffer_size += frameSize;
                firstFU = false;
}
```

if you find another prefix i.e. nal_type equal 39 in my case, send temp_rtp_data to the decoder, hope it helps.